# Dynamic array in VBA

Tags: arrays, excel, vba, compiler-errors

Im learning programing logic with VBA and im trying to do a array, but i have a error in the running

```
Dim auxTexto As String
Dim auxNumero As Long
Dim auxIterador As Integer

Dim auxArrayEstatico(0 To 5) As Integer
Dim auxArrayDinamico As String


Sub prueba()

    auxTexto = "Hola"
    auxNumero = 1
    
    auxArrayEstatico(0) = 2
    auxArrayEstatico(1) = 2
    auxArrayEstatico(2) = 2
    auxArrayEstatico(3) = 2
    auxArrayEstatico(4) = 2
    
    MsgBox ("Valor de Array en posicion 3 es " & auxArrayEstatico(3))
    
    ReDim auxArrayDinamico(0 To 3)
    auxArrayDinamico(0) = "Hola"
    
    MsgBox (auxArrayDinamico(0))
    
End Sub
```

The error say "Error of copilation, expected a array"
Please, somebody can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

removed "as string", also moved variables inside sub.

For faster debugging, try replacing `msgbox "hola"...` with `debug.print "hola"...`. this will just send the text to the immediate window for quick viewing.

```
Option Explicit
Sub prueba()

Dim auxTexto As String
Dim auxNumero As Long
Dim auxIterador As Integer

Dim auxArrayEstatico(0 To 5) As Integer
Dim auxArrayDinamico

    auxTexto = "Hola"
    auxNumero = 1
    
    auxArrayEstatico(0) = 2
    auxArrayEstatico(1) = 2
    auxArrayEstatico(2) = 2
    auxArrayEstatico(3) = 2
    auxArrayEstatico(4) = 2
    
    MsgBox ("Valor de Array en posicion 3 es " & auxArrayEstatico(3))
    
    ReDim auxArrayDinamico(0 To 3)
    auxArrayDinamico(0) = "Hola"
    
    MsgBox (auxArrayDinamico(0))
    
End Sub
```

Comment: Removing "as string" works because VBA interprets the declaration to be implicitly `Variant`.  It is better to declare explicitly: `Dim auxArrayDinamico As Variant`.

Comment: Thanks @CameronCritchlow, can you explain me why i must place variables inside sub?

Comment: @BZngr thanks, your answer was really help, which is the difference beetween `As String` and `As Variant`

Comment: When declaring any variable you need to specify the data type. [See here for more info](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/data-type-summary)